# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six' | python =3.10 | six is already installed

Tags: python-3.x, apt-get, modulenotfounderror, six

I am getting below "No module named 'six'" , but it is already installed

```
sudo virtualenv ve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..app_data import make_app_data
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/app_data/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .na import AppDataDisabled
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/app_data/na.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .base import AppData, ContentStore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/app_data/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'


python -c "import six; print (six.__version__)"
1.16.0
```

Already tried steps (didn't work)

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-virtualenv 
sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv 
pip3 uninstall six
pip3 install six
sudo virtualenv ve  (throws error)
pip3 install urllib3 --upgrade
```

version:

- python 3.10
- six 1.16

Comment: Do you have multiple python installs? Eg `python` and `python3`?

Comment: yes i have multiple python,
No this is not a duplicate question,
using "pip show six" I saw where is it stored, it was just six.py, copied this file in the path where the above file was throwing error, and everything worked,

Comment: do comment if others are facing similar issue with other pip installs